# Google Finance Tesco

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance, google-finance-api

I am using GoogleFinance() function in Google Sheet for some stocks statistics, but I have problem with some tickers like Tesco (London). If I try GoogleFinance("TSCO", something), I get values of Tractor Supply Company (NASDAQ), because both are TSCO. Is there any possibility, to get Tesco (and other stocks with duplicate tickers)?

Thanks

[image: same tickers]

Comment: not all tickers are supported under google finance

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/tsco?countrycode=uk",
 "//span[@class='value']")
```

[image]